# Preventing the regeneration of the JS chunk if only the styles changed

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here's my watch config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

var extractStyl = ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
  'style',
  'css?modules&localIdentName=[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:5]!stylus'
)


module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.ts',

  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: './public/'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.ts(x?)$/, loader: 'ts', exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.styl$/, loader: extractStyl }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
  ]
}
```

Whenever I make a style change, both the javascript and css outputs are recreated. However I sometimes use browsersync which can hot-reload css changes but since the javascript output always update with the css (even if the output is exactly the same, the file changes), it decides to reload the page entirely.

How can a change to a .styl not do a null update to the js output ? I suspect this is due to me only having one chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this workaround: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1530#issuecomment-179711478

Though if someone has a better, more idiomatic way I'd try it for sure.